# how to dynamically add html content with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I want to dynamically add HTML content with `angularJs`, but getting and error:

```
"$compile is not defined"
```

What can be the reason?

Code

```
<td ng-repeat="user in users[0].yds" data-title="'Timeline'" sortable="timeline" style="text-align: center" >
    <div class="circle_dynamic"></div>
</td>


angular.module('elnApp')
  .controller('ProgramtableCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $filter, ngTableParams,    
     programTableService) {
        for(var i=0; i<=$scope.users[0].projects.length; i++){
            for(var j=0; j<$scope.users[0].projects[i].results.length; j++){

                if($scope.users[0].projects[i].results[j] == 0){

                    $(".circle_dynamic").html(
                      $compile(
                         ""
                      )(scope)
                    );
                    console.log('rm')
                }else{

                    $(".circle_dynamic").html(
                      $compile(
                         "<i ng-class='circle_class' style='position: absolute;'></i>"
                      )(scope)
                    );
                    console.log('add')
                }
            }

        }

    }, true);

}});
```

how to add html content dynamically?  please help

Comment: Where is this this code? In directive? In controller? Show us how you initialize it.

Comment: this is in controller

Comment: Why do you need to call $compile? Even if you do, you should do it in a directive and not in a controller.

Comment: I bet you have strong jQuery background? I advice you to read the official tutorial and documentation because what you're doing is against Angular's conventions - this will make your development difficult and frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `$compile` here.

Note: Hardcoding index `$scope.users[0].projects.length` doesn't seem logically correct to me, are you sure you want that?

These lines in your code are very confusing. It will be easier for you to get the answer if you tell what is the data structure of user (ie. the relation between user, project and result) and  what you want to achieve.

```
for(var i=0; i<=$scope.users[0].projects.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<$scope.users[0].projects[i].results.length; j++){
```

The following solution is assuming that

`users` is an array of users.

Each `user` has many `projects`, so `user.projects` is an array.

You want to show a div with `class="circle_class"` for each result if it exists.

With these assumptions, the following should be enough.

```
<td ng-repeat="user in users[0].yds"
    data-title="'Timeline'"
    sortable="timeline"
    style="text-align: center" >
  <div ng-repeat="project in user.projects">
    <div ng-repeat="result in project.results"
         ng-show="result">
      <i ng-class='circle_class' style='position: absolute;'></i>
      </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: And what is i, j? Confusing part is you are iterating over users and showing results of projects of just the first user. If you really want that then define something like `var projectOwner = $scope.users[0]` and use it so that it will be clear.

Comment: This code will show icons for each results if result is one (non zero) for each project for each user. It doesn't show icons if the result is  0.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add html content `ng-bindHtmlUnsafe` would do the trick.

In HTML

```
<div class="circle_dynamic" ng-bindHtmlUnsafe={{expression}}></div>
```

In controller

```
$scope.expression="<i ng-class='circle_class' style='position: absolute;'></i>"
```

See documentation [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtmlUnsafe)

Comment: You shouldn't try to modify DOM in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

In angularjs, as a best practice you should use directives for DOM manipulations

Why do you need to compile it?

Answer (score 0):

"$compile is not defined" occurs because you forgot to inject it into your Controller.

Dynamically add HTML content with $compile is OK. But don't do it in your controller. Do it in a directive.